# What would prevent me from being able to upload images on migrated products?

Tags: magento2.2.6

I recently did a product migration to Magento 2. If I create a new product I can upload pictures. If a product has images I can upload images. We do a nightly sync with our erp and if a product was created with that I can add images. The only time I can't add pictures is if the product came over as a migrated product and had no images.Everything else about the product works fine. When I upload a picture it shows but when I click save it vanishes. There are no errors. How

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is what I got back from Magento and it seems to have worked. Hope it helps someone.

It was the incorrect backend_type of the media_gallery attribute. To fix this, please run the SQL query:

UPDATEeav_attributeSETbackend_type= 'static' WHEREattribute_id= '88';

and flush cache.